# combining values in two columns in to a single new column in R

Tags: r, date, data-transform

How can i combine two columns such that the value in one column replaces NA in the other column?

## Initial dataframe

```
date1                         date2
2016-08-29 02:31:34            NA
NA                      2016-08-29 17:59:23
```

## Data frame after transformation

```
date1                         date2                     Newdate
2016-08-29 02:31:34            NA                 2016-08-29 02:31:34 
NA                      2016-08-29 17:59:23       2016-08-29 17:59:23
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `dplyr::coalesce(...)`

Data - note `coalesce` does not work with factors

```
df <- read.table(text="date1,date2
2016-08-29 02:31:34,NA
NA,2016-08-29 17:59:23", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Solution

```
df$dates <- dplyr::coalesce(df$date1, df$date2)
                # date1               date2               dates
# 1 2016-08-29 02:31:34                <NA> 2016-08-29 02:31:34
# 2                <NA> 2016-08-29 17:59:23 2016-08-29 17:59:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
# Simulating your data
date1 <- c("2016-08-29 02:31:34", NA)
date2 <- c(NA, "2016-08-29 17:59:23")
df <- data.frame(date1, date2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Actual solution
Newdate <- df$date1 # Copy the values from date1
Newdate[is.na(df$date1)] <- date2[is.na(df$date1)] # Replace every position where date1 is NA.
df$Newdate <- Newdate # Create the new column
print(df)
```

Hope it helps! :)